# List of macOS text editors and code editors

Tags: macos, editor

I searched for this and found [Maudite's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1632/maudite) question about [text editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155/text-editors#14203) but they were all for Windows.

As you have no doubt guessed, I am trying to find out if there are any text/code editors for the Mac besides what I know of. I'll edit my post to include editors listed.

#### Free

1. [Textwrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/)
2. [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/)
3. [Mac Vim](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim)
4. [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) and closer to the original [EMacs](http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html)
5. [JEdit](http://www.jedit.org/)
6. [Editra](http://editra.org/)
7. [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/)
8. [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mac.html)
9. [Kod](http://kodapp.com/)
10. [TextMate2](https://github.com/textmate/textmate#readme) - GPL
11. [Brackets](http://brackets.io/)
12. [Atom.io](https://atom.io/)

#### Commercial

1. [Textmate](https://macromates.com/)
2. [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)
3. [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/)
4. [Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/)
5. [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)
6. [Smultron](http://smultron.sourceforge.net/)
7. [WebStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/)
8. [Peppermint](http://osxpeppermint.com)

#### Articles related to the subject

1. [Faceoff, which is the best text editor ever?](http://mac360.com/index.php/mac360/comments/faceoff_which_is_the_best_text_editor_ever/)
2. [Maceditors.com, mac editors features compared](http://maceditors.com)

Thank you everybody that has added suggestions.

Comment: Also worth checking out http://alternativeto.net/software/vim/?platform=mac , which is probably a better forum for something like this.

Comment: Check out Nevron docs - https://docs.nevron.com/

Comment: So, why is this question on-topic here?

Comment: not constructive ? wth ?

Comment: Found an updated list which was useful -> https://learnwoo.com/best-code-editors-mac-windows-edit-wordpress-woocommerce-php-js-css-files/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but another **free** one that I've heard good thing about is [Smultron](http://smultron.sourceforge.net/).

In my own research on this, I found this interesting article:
[Faceoff: Which Is The Best Mac Text Editor Ever?](http://mac360.com/index.php/mac360/comments/faceoff_which_is_the_best_text_editor_ever/)

Comment: smultron is no longer free

Comment: Smultron also abandons each version. (Version 5 for Mountain Lion, Version 6 for Mavericks, etc). You have to rebuy each version.

Answer (score 22):

I thought TextMate was everyone's favourite. I haven't met a programmer using a Mac who is not using TextMate.

Comment: I'm using MacVim and I can say that it is worth every penny I paid.. for TextMate. =)

Comment: I use SubEthaEdit. I'm still happy with it, and whilst I've looked at TextMate, there's never been a real reason for me to change.

Comment: Oh, and I still use Xcode for Cocoa and Java programming.

Comment: Once you learn to use some of the shortcuts in TextMate it will become clear why so many developers use it :) Second choice: VIM :)

Comment: TextMate is horrible and only handles 2-3 fonts..

Answer (score 13):

- Emacs
- Vim

But I use TextMate, and can say that it is, without a doubt, worth every penny I paid for it.

Comment: Just a +1 from a very satisfied TextMate user (reg. #63).

Answer (score 12):

Sublime text is awesome (http://www.sublimetext.com/2). Excellent search features, very fast and lightweight. Very decent code completion.

I also use RubyMine and WebStorm a lot (http://www.jetbrains.com/). They are excellent but not all purpose like TextMate.

Answer (score 5):

[MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) and [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/) are two nice options

Answer (score 5):

I've tried Komodo out a bit, and I really like it so far. Aptana, an Eclipse variant, is also rather useful for a wide variety of things. There's always good ole' VI, too!

Answer (score 5):

If you ever plan on making a serious effort at learning Emacs, immediately forget about Aquamacs. It tries to twist and bend Emacs into something it's not (a super-native OS X app). That might sound well and all, but once you realize that it completely breaks nearly every standard keybinding and behavior of Emacs, you begin to wonder why you aren't just using TextEdit or TextMate.

Carbon Emacs is a good Emacs application for OS X. It is as close as you'll get to GNU Emacs without compiling for yourself. It fits in well enough with the operating system, but at the same time, is the wonderful Emacs we all know and love. Currently it requires Leopard with the latest release, but most people have upgraded by now anyway. You can fetch it [here](http://homepage.mac.com/zenitani/emacs-e.html).

Alternatively, if you want to use Vim on OS X, I've heard good things about [MacVim](http://macvim.org/OSX/index.php).

Beyond those, there are the obvious TextEdit, TextMate, etc line of editors. They work for some people, but most "advanced" users I know (myself included) hate touching them with anything shorter than a 15ft pole.

Comment: This comment is a subjective judgement. If Aquamacs were so broken it would hardly be being used by so many. Aquamacs definitely binds the Mac UX onto Emacs primarily for Mac users who are used to a certain behavior. Longtime Emacs users will have to unlearn which is why it is not a good choice for them. Conversly, Mac users will find the normal Emacs UX odd. If you are planning to use Emacs cross-platform on Windows and Linux, then learn Emacs would be my advice.

Answer (score 5):

[CotEditor](https://coteditor.com) is a Cocoa-based open source text editor. It is popular in Japan.

Answer (score 4):

Best open source one is [Smultron](http://smultron.sourceforge.net/) in my opinion, but it doesn't a torch to TextMate.

Answer (score 4):

There's a new kid on the block - [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/). I used it for a whole year. Its not free but offers an individual license of 49$ for a year, free for Open Source Developers.

- **Speedy for an IDE** - Its based on Java so looks somewhat like Eclipse/Netbeans but smokes them to dust in terms of speed (not as fast as Coda/Textmate as this is an IDE).
- **Keyboard shortcuts galore** - I seldom touched the mouse while developing using PHPStorm (that's what I didn't like about Coda)
- **Subversion support built-in** - Didn't need to touch Versions or any other SVN client on Mac
- **Supports snippets, templates** - zen-coding is supported as well
- **Supports projects**, though in separate windows
- File search, code search
- **code completion**, supports PHPDoc code completion too

Answer (score 3):

- BBEdit makes all other editors look like Notepad.

It handles gigantic files with ease; most text editors (TextMate especially) slow down to a dead crawl or just crash when presented with a large file.

The regexp and multiple-file Find dialogs beat anything else for usability.

The clippings system works like magic, and has selection, indentation, placeholder, and insertion point tags, it's not just dumb text.

BBEdit is heavily AppleScriptable. Everything can be scripted.

In 9.0, BBEdit has code completion, projects, and a ton of other improvements.

I primarily use it for HTML, CSS, JS, and Python, where it's extremely strong. Some more obscure languages are not as well-supported in it, but for most purposes it's fantastic.

The only devs I know who like TextMate are Ruby fans. I really do not get the appeal, it's marginally better than TextWrangler (BBEdit's free little brother), but if you're spending money, you may as well buy the better tool for a few dollars more.

- jEdit does have the virtue of being cross-platform. It's not nearly as good as BBEdit, but it's a competent programmer's editor. If you're ever faced with a Windows or Linux system, it's handy to have one tool you know that works.
- Vim is fine if you have to work over ssh and the remote system or your computer can't do X11. I used to love Vim for the ease of editing large files and doing repeated commands. But these days, it's a no-vote for me, with the annoyance of the non-standard search & replace (using (foo) groups instead of (foo), etc.), painfully bad multi-document handling, lack of a project/disk browser view, lack of AppleScript, and bizarre mouse handling in the GVim version.

Comment: BBEdit doesnt support collaborative editing..

Comment: I sometimes miss how stupid notepad.exe is. Low memory usage, quick, fast, and does a very minimal amount of stuff

Answer (score 2):

[jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) runs on OS X, being Java-based. It's somewhat similar to TextMate, I think.

[Editra](http://editra.org/) looks interesting, but I've not tried it myself.

Answer (score 2):

TextMate not for "advanced programmers". That does not make sense, TextMate contains everything an "advanced programmer" would want. It allows them to define a bundle that allows them to quickly set up the way they want their source code formatted, or one that follows the project guidelines, quick easy access to create entire structures and classes based on typing part of a construct and hitting tab.

TextMate is my tool of choice, it is fast, lightweight and yet contains all of the features I would want in a tool to program with. While it is not tightly integrated in Xcode, that is not a problem for me as I don't write software for Mac OS X. I write software for FreeBSD.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely [BBEdit](https://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/). I code, and BBEdit is what I use to code.

Answer (score 1):

- [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) and its variants.
- [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/mac.html)

Comment: lol, who wants an IDE when u can just use an editor.

Comment: these are full-blown IDEs, not text editors.

Answer (score 1):

- [SubEthaEdit](https://subethaedit.net/)
- [Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/)
- [DashCode](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Dashcode_UserGuide/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Introduction/Introduction.html) with OS X 10.8 or **older**

Answer (score 1):

[Smultron](http://smultron.sourceforge.net/) is another good (and free) one.

Comment: Link doesn't work - double http

Answer (score 1):

I use [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/) as my primary editor (for Python) but I always keep [SubEthaEdit](https://subethaedit.net/) handy as my supplemental text editor (free trial, 30 euros to license). It's not super-complicated but it does what I need.

Comment: For python in this day and age PyCharm is the way, imo. Eclipse was originally created by IBM which happened to hate Sun Microsystems — hence the name, Eclipse was supposed to eclipse Sun :D Ironically today Intellij products by far eclipse the Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider one of the classics - they're both free, extensible and have large user bases that extend beyond the Mac:

- [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) - emacs for OS X (emacs in a shell window is also an option)
- [Mac Vim](http://macvim.org/) - VI with a Mac-specific GUI (vim in a shell window is also an option)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer an old-school editing setup. I use command-line vim embedded in a [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) "window" inside of [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/).

This may not integrate well with XCode, but I think it works great for developing and using command-line programs. If you spend any significant time working in a terminal, GNU Screen is worth the 30 minutes it takes to master the basic terminal multiplexing concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Coda's great for PHP/ASP/HTML style development.  Great interface, multiple-file search and replace with regexp support, slick FTP/SFTP/etc integration for browsing and editing remote files, SVN integration, etc.

It now supports plugins and the plugin editor can import TextMate bundles, so there's a bright future there.  There aren't a lot of must-have plugins yet because the plugin support was newly introduced with version 1.6 a few months back.  It's a popular app, though, so I expect more in the future.

The "killer features" for me are:
* Seamless editing of remote files
* Code navigator (symbol browser; pane that lists functions etc)

Most people aren't really into using symbol browsers but as I have to maintain a lot of unfamiliar code I find them invaluable.

I'm not sure that Coda has the "raw power" of TextMate though.  I plan on getting familiar with TextMate next.

Answer (score 1):

I make use of Komodo IDE. It supports a huge number of languages, and is customisable but is a bit expensive (my company bought me a copy). A really good alternative is the free version called Komodo Edit. Loads really quickly and has a decent feature list and I find myself turning to it rather than the full IDE for a lot of jobs.

Answer (score 1):

[Fraise](https://github.com/jfmoy/Fraise) is a nice free option. It has some rough edges, but you can't beat the price. I believe it's a fork or successor of Smultron.

[image: Fraise Text Editor for MacOS]

Comment: It is a fork of Smultron.  Unfortunately, it's the only fork of Smultron and the author has abandoned it in favour of a ground-up rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer [EditRocket](http://www.editrocket.com/) over TextMate.  I use it on both my Mac and Ubuntu machines.  It is nice to use the same editor on multiple operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

Textmate is state of the Art editor, but if someone is thinking about developing on several platforms without awkward memory eaters monsters like jedit, eclipse, netbeans etc take a look at geany (geany.org). It is free. The only problem the editor has not esthetic look and feel on Mac OS X :)

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for Smultron. I used it when doing some XQuery programming and being able to define a keyword files for syntax color highlighting was great.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed both Smultron and Textwrangler, but find myself using Smultron most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I would love to use a different editor than XCode for coding, but I feel, that no other editor integrates tightly enough with it to be really worthwhile.
However, given some time, TextMate might eventually get to that point. At the moment though, it primarily lacks debugging features and refactoring.

For everything that does not need XCode, I love TextMate. If I had another Mac-user in my workgroup I would probably consider SubEthaEdit for its collaboration features. If it is Emacs you want, I would recommend Aquamacs (more Mac-like) or Carbon Emacs (more GNU-Emacs-like)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using BBEdit for years. It's rock-solid, fast, and integrates into my Xcode workflow decently well. (I'm not sure anything integrates into Xcode as well as the built-in editor, but who has time to wait for the built-in editor?)

For small team projects which don't use a source control system, or for single user editing on multiple machines, SubEthaEdit comes highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and Netbeans have text editors among a whole lot of other stuff. I don't think you would want to wait 10 seconds for your text editor to become ready :/...If you are going to spend some serious time coding then spend some time and learn to use vim (emacs too but, I recommend vim)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using TextWrangler, it's pretty decent.

But I REALLY miss the Search and Replace and other capabilities of UltraEdit... enough that it's usually worth firing up Parallels to use it instead (UltraEdit runs poorly under Wine at the moment).

Comment: Command+F gives you a pretty powerful search and replace window.. A cursory glance over the UltraEdit website doesn't show anything that might not be possible in TextWrangler.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that i love Coda, it can do almost anything you need in 'plain' text WebDevelopent,
i use it daily to develop simple and complex projects using XHTML,PHP,Javascript,CSS...

Ok, it's not free but compare it with many other development suits and you'll find that that 100$ are really affordable (i bought many months ago when it was at about 60$)
In the last version they included a lot of new nice features and whoa... just look at [the panic WebSite](http://www.panic.com/coda/)

Before using coda i was a hardcore ZendStudio User, i used that in Windows,Linux and Mac (i have been user for a long time for all that platforms)  as it was developed in Java it was really slow even in a modern MacBookPro.. so i also tested a lots of diferent IDEs for developing but at this moment any of these are as powerful and simple as Coda is

Answer (score 0):

I used to use PageSpiner from optima Software (http://www.optima-system.com/pagespinner/) but converted to Coda when Panic first released it and haven't looked back.

Now that the latest version has multi-file find and replace it has just about everything I need and I use it on a daily basis. Another vote for Coda from me.

Answer (score 0):

I used BBEdit for years, but recently converted to Panic's Coda.

I love Coda. It does everything that I need and now that I've begun programming plug-ins for it, it's become a far more rich tool. The support team are responsive and the community that is growing around it is fantastic. There is still a lot of room for improvement, but that's the cool thing about being part of the kind of community that surrounds it; you have a say in what that improvement is.

[Panic - Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/)

Answer (score 0):

My vote would be for BBedit's free little brother [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/).

Answer (score 0):

I purchased Textmate because I liked it so much, one of the few apps I paid for. Other editors are just not worth it. If you are going for an IDE, eclipse or netbeans are great and free.

Answer (score 0):

I use Xcode and TextMate.

Answer (score 0):

Mac UltraEdit is out as of 2011 - http://www.ultraedit.com/products/mac-text-editor.html

Very much a 1.0-ish feel and sluggish (though labeled 2.0.2), has all the great features of the Windows version (column edits, true hex mode, full out macro recording, and plugins for every language under the sun).

Comment: I'm using Mac Ultraedit and I'm still not sold on it. Very buggy and clumsy, for instance changing colors is insanely stupid. I keep saying what for the next patch but it still kinda sucks.

Answer (score -1):

I like Aptana Studio and Redcar for rails programming.