# Most feature-full collaborative editor for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, editor, text-editor, collaboration

I'm looking for a collaborative editor that doesn't suck :) And that at least supports Ruby syntax highlighting. Also, a developer and I will be using this to program, so Google Docs won't work.

In all reality, I just need a collaborative editor that has the concept of a project. Where both users see the folder structure of a project and thus see what the other user has opened and is editing.

Also, it would be ideal that both users have local copies of the data (none of this "You remote into me and don't get to keep the data when we're done" stuff) so that one can actively develop against each other's code.

Truthfully, I've found such an editor: http://www.n-brain.net/una_ide.html#features

But I'd really like to see if there's something else out there that's just killer.

I've tried ECF and Eclipse, and it seems SO promising, but NONE of the Ruby IDE's implement the very simple methods of incorporating ECF document sharing functionality into them.

So, does anyone actively use Collaborative editors? And if so, what's your setup like?

Answer (score 5):

[SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/) is an excellent collaborative editor.  It allows multiple users to edit files simultaneously, and chat about it.  So far it is the best thing I've found for this sort of thing.

Comment: I've used SubEthaEdit before, but from what I remember: 1) The user hosting was the only person who had the files on his/her physical disk, and 2) It didn't support multiple documents being opened.

Does it support these now?

Comment: 1) Yes, a user shares the file. [I'm not sure how the opposite would work!] 2) No, you can have as many files open as you want.

Comment: 1) Sounds like you should look into a SCM system.

Comment: Well, ideally, this would work on top of a SCM (we use git and github). You see, if two programmers were banging away on some of the same files, it wouldn't make sense that the connecting programmer couldn't test his own code by running it via the terminal. Simply editing and not testing isn't ideal

Answer (score 1):

[Coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/) licenses SubEthaEdit and includes the same collaborative functionality. Coda also has a notion of a project including directory structure.

Comment: My main question about the SubEtha Engine is whether or not it places the remote session's changes in the local file... this is key, because it doesn't make much sense that say, two programmers were able to code in the same doc, but not test their code in their own environments...

Answer (score 0):

SubEthaEdit is quite the tool. I love it.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two different questions there.

For Ruby on Rails, you probably want this one: [Aptna RadRails](http://www.radrails.org/).

For collaborative editor, I haven't tried any collaborative editor myself (other than SubEtha, tho not for actual collaboration). But if you haven't looked yet, here are some options you may wish to try:

- [Zoho Writer](http://writer.zoho.com/), which is a better Google Docs
- [Bespin](http://labs.mozilla.com/projects/bespin/), from Mozilla
- [beWeeVee Notepad](http://www.beweevee.com/), an off-stream online alternative

I got 'em all from [AlternativeTo.net](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/subethaedit/)

Answer (score 0):

[Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) (Emacs for Mac they call it) is pretty much feature rich 
and supports collaborative editing as well. Its hard to beat that in feature list. See [this list on wiki to do a comparison yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors). And best of all, its open source! Then there is [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/) too but doesn't have collaborative editing.

[Also see this original question for a comprehensive list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533/mac-text-code-editor)