# Favorite IDE/Code Editor for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mac text/code editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533/mac-text-code-editor)

What's your favorite Code Editor or IDE for Mac OS X?

Note: An associate and myself found a newer Code Editor, WYSIWIG style, about a month ago, and cannot recollect it's name or find it anywhere on the net. It was referred to in several articles as the 'Dreamweaver Killer,' and it's fairly new [within 6 months]. If you name this editor, your answer is the winner ... we've been racking our minds and pulling our hair out for about 3 hours.

Comment: http://www.google.nl/search?rlz=1C1DVCB_enNL336NL346&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=mac+os+x+%22dreamweaver+killer%22

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Flux](http://www.theescapers.com/flux/).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a full-blown IDE, TextMate is an exceptionally good programmer's editor.

Comment: I love TextMate, it's really a far-reaching, powerful application in a tiny capsule. I've went back and forth between Coda and TextMate for a while and since I learned you can mount an FTP and load into TextMate, I may be sticking with it. But none-the-less, Flux is what I was searching for ... teaching newbies :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I use VIM (in the console), but SubEthaEdit, TextMate and TextWrangler are popular editors I know.

Comment: I have a feeling that VIM is neither new nor a WYSIWYG "dreamweaver killer".

Comment: Hey, it's just 19 years old ! And it can underline links in HTML ;-P