# Good Free Rails IDE for OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide

I have tried Eclipse, Aptana, Redcar, Textedit, Komodo Edit, Titanium, Netbeans, and Vim. Is there anything you can think of that i'm missing? None of these really satisfy me.

Comment: What are you looking for in a IDE that these fails to deliver?

Comment: Fredrik is spot on, no one can help you if you don't tell us what you are looking for.

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533/mac-text-code-editor

Comment: Please refine a feature set you are looking for

Comment: Honestly, there is no particular featue that i am searching for, i justy wanted to explore any options i might have been missing before deciding on one to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question here is what are you looking on an IDE? what must they have for you to like it? In particular, I use Vim with this https://github.com/joseicosta/janus-tweaks. This provides me all I want, and with the lightness inherent to vim.

Answer (score -2):

TextMate is a popular "IDE" that runs on OS X only.  It costs $$, but well worth it.

Comment: What the hell man!  How is TextMate not a rails IDE?  You can run tests, run generators, integrate git, just about anything vim or emacs does.  Thanks for my first downvotes ever, ingrates.

Comment: I think the down votes are probably because it doesn't answer the question. The OP specifically asks for free.