# Unix grep command outputs garbage

Tags: macos, unix, grep, garbage

I´m executing the following command "grep bruno < bash.txt " which gives me the right output "bruno" and garbage "\f0\fs24 \cf0".

I´m on the command shell on a Mac OS X v10.6.8 and i´m pretty sure i should be getting the line of the found word and the word. Not garbage.

This is the Output:

```
Mobile-Devs-MacBook-Pro:Screenshots Poupe mdev$ grep bruno < bash.txt  
\f0\fs24 \cf0 bruno\
```

In bash.txt i only have written "bruno", if i output with "cat bash.txt" it also gives me the following garbage:

```
Mobile-Devs-MacBook-Pro:Screenshots Poupe mdev$ cat bash.txt
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1038\cocoasubrtf360
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\paperw11900\paperh16840\margl1440\margr1440\vieww9000\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\tx566\tx1133\tx1700\tx2267\tx2834\tx3401\tx3968\tx4535\tx5102\tx5669\tx6236\tx6803\ql\qnatural\pardirnatural

\f0\fs24 \cf0 bruno\
```

If i make "echo bruno > bash.txt" and then "cat bash.txt" it gives me a clean output. Why am i not seeing a clean output when i write the file by hand?

Comment: What does the line look like in `bash.txt`?

Comment: i only have "bruno". I wrote by hand and it gives me garbage, but if i do "echo bruno > bash.txt" and then "cat bash.txt", it shows me "bruno" without garbage. Why is the output only clean when i use echo and not when i write by hand?

Comment: What editor did you use to created `bash.txt`? A word processor?

Comment: I used TextEdit, which doesn´t allow me to save as a txt. Only doc, docx, xml, .odt, html. So if i want a clean text, what should i use?

Comment: Now i created the file with "echo bruno > bash.txt" and it gave me a clean file, with a clean output.

Comment: My answer explains both of these.

Comment: Also, the "which text editor should I use" question has been answered many times before. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533/mac-text-code-editor and see "Related".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file isn't a plain text file. It is [RTF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format). `grep` is giving you the line containing "bruno", along with the rich text formatting.

When you do:

```
echo bruno > bash.txt
```

bash.txt contains only "bruno".

When you "edit the file by hand", your editor is saving as RTF. You need to save as plain text.

[image: Plain Text]

Comment: Thanks man. This is correct, i just don´t have that option on my editor.

Comment: The screenshot was taken from TextEdit v1.7 (289.3).

Comment: TextEdit 1.12 (329) has a "Make Plain Text" under the Format menu. If the file is already in plain text format (or after conversion), the menu is (changes to) "Make Rich Text".

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a plain text file. That looks like an RTF. Grep only understands text and its job is to output the entire line where the search text is found.

I cannot tell from your formatting, but I have to believe the "garbage" you are seeing is on the same line as the "bruno" text.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is that the file is in RTF format, and contains formatting information.  If you want to create a plain text file in TextEdit, use the menu option Format > Make Plain Text before saving it.  Better yet, don't use TextEdit at all -- my favorite for plain text editing is [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/), but there are plenty of other options.

Comment: "TextWrangler is not compatible with macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) or later. Please install and use BBEdit instead." (from TextWrangler/BBEdit website)