# Open source text editor for Mac

Tags: macos, open-source, editor

Does anybody know about any living open source text programming (mainly html/css) editor for Mac? There does not seem to be one.

[Kod](https://github.com/rsms/kod) - dead
[Fraise](https://github.com/jfmoy/Fraise) - dead
Smultron - not open source anymore
Coda - not open source

I would like to extend it with CSS live preview tab, but in order to do that it has to be open source, and I would prefer working on a project that has some perspective. Everything seems to be on the Mac App Store now... :\

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mac text/code editor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533/mac-text-code-editor)

Comment: Doesn't [Espresso](http://www.macrabbit.com/espresso/) have a live preview?

Comment: Here's a short list off the top of my head: Aquamacs (and various less-Mac-ish emacsen), Editra, Eclipse, jEdit, NetBeans, almost anything designed for Qt/KDE or GNOME/Gtk…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TextMate 2 is now open-sourced on github.
https://github.com/textmate/textmate#readme

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, learn Vim. It'll take you a while at first, but you won't regret it.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not about that. Vim is great and I use it regularly, but I want a regular tabbed OSS editor so that I can go into the code and add Live Preview.

Comment: Not open source but TextMate is great. I think that's the premiere programmer text editor for mac. But, it is kind of pricey unfortunately.