# How can I edit a Dockerfile in a Mac terminal?

Tags: macos, docker, terminal, dockerfile, text-editor

I can add lines on to a Makefile on a Mac terminal via echo command

But how can I edit a Dockerfile similarly?

The first line of the Dockerfile reads

```
FROM eosio/eos-dev:v1.2.4
```

But since that docker repo is deprecated, I need to replace the first line with some other docker repo I found but I also want to create a shell script file that automatically does it.

I tried on the Mac terminal

```
echo 'FROM somerepo/somerepo-dev' >> Dockerfile
```

but it doesn't do what I intend to do.

I tried a simple echo 'FROM somerepo/somerepo-dev' >> Dockerfile but it doesn't work.

FROM eosio/eos-dev:v1.2.4

replace the first line of the dockerfile with some other docker repo

Comment: See: [List of macOS text editors and code editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533/list-of-macos-text-editors-and-code-editors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using echo command on the terminal

```
sed -i -e 's/FROM eosio\/eos-dev:v1.2.4/FROM somerepo\/somerepo-dev/g' Dockerfile
```

solved the issue

there was no need to identify which line. I just have to specify everything within the line I wanted to replace