# SSRS BIDS Unexpected end of file has occurred

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bids

I have come accross the following error in BIDS whilst working on one of my report parts.

At the time I was playing around with an image that I imported into the project around 6 times, Visual Studio threw up an error about performance or memory, I re-booted and now this is all I see everytime I bring up the report part.

I Have opened up the report that was deployed to the server the last time it was working in report builder 3.0, re-saved it in my project folder and attempted to re-add it to the project but it still throws up the error.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible (without guessing) to answer your question, but if treated as "Any suggestions for investigating" there's one thing that helped me out more than once:

Open the RDL as code, either in Visual Studio or your [Text Editor of choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155/windows-based-text-editors), and go through the RDL to see any problems. It's just an[XML document](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd), and more often than not this kind of problem can be sorted out by skimming that XML for obvious problems. Note that embedded images are inside the RDL in elements, with its content encoded.

If you have a VCS in place (as you probably should :D) then it's probably even easier to solve. Use your VCS's diff tool to see what's changed in the RDL. Similar to the suggestion above, there's probably something fishy going on with the file and its embedded images elements.

Comment: I reimported a previous version of the report into Visual Studio and it sorted the problem. Thanks for the suggestions.